# Compare differences in 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am running a MySQL Server on Ubuntu, patched up to date...

In MySQL, I have 2 tables in a database.  I am trying to get a stock query change working and it kind of is, but it's not :(

What I have is a table (table A) that holds the last time I have checked stock levels, and another table (table B) that holds current stock levels.  Each table has identical column names and types.

What I want to do is report on the changes from `table B.`  The reason is that there are about 1/2 million items in this table - and I cannot just update each item using the table as a source as I am limited to 100 changes at a time.  So, ideally, I want to get the changes - store them in a temporary table, and use that table to update our system with just those changes...

The following below brings back the changes but shows both `Table A and Table B`.

I have tried using a Left Join to only report back on `Table B` but I'm not a mysql (or any SQL) guy, and googling all this...  Can anyone help please.  TIA.  Stuart

```
SELECT StockItemName,StockLevel
FROM (
SELECT StockItemName,StockLevel FROM stock
UNION ALL
SELECT StockItemName,StockLevel FROM stock_copy
) tbl
GROUP BY StockItemName,StockLevel
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY StockItemName;
```

Comment: This seems like an interesting question, but it is hard to formulate a query because you haven't shown us any data.  Please add some brief sample data from both tables, and then ideally show us what the output should be.

Comment: This would be one table A (with column names at the top)

StockItem StockItemName Warehouse ReorderLevel MinimumLevel MaximumLevel StockLevel QuantityOnOrder QuantityInStock QuantityAllocated FreeStock
..11-800-07 11-800-07 Ansell 11- HOME 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 2.00000 0.0 2.00000 0.0 2.00000""..11-800-
..11-800-09 11-800-09 Ansell 11- HOME 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0""..11-800-09

Comment: This would be the other table - Table B
StockItem StockItemName Warehouse ReorderLevel MinimumLevel MaximumLevel StockLevel QuantityOnOrder QuantityInStock QuantityAllocated FreeStock ..11-800-07 11-800-07 Ansell 11- HOME 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.0 2.00000 0.0 2.00000""..11-800- ..11-800-09 11-800-09 Ansell 11- HOME 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0""..11-800-09 –

Comment: Table A would be the new data and as you can see, the stock Level on Table A is 1 higher.
So, I would want to compare the levels on A and B, matching the StockItemName and take the stock level on A as the absolute.

Comment: I added more to the original issue as it gives the reason why I am trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The query below spit out records that have different stock level in both table.

```
SELECT s.StockItemName, s.StockLevel, sc.StockLevel
FROM stock s
LEFT JOIN stock_copy sc ON sc.Id = s.Id AND sc.StockLevel <> s.StockLevel
ORDER BY s.StockItemName
```

Comment: I tried copying and pasting - it produced an error on sc.ID saying unknown column sc.ID

I changed this to s.StockItemName (and sc.StockItemName) but then it ran for 30 minutes and then lost connection.

Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Do you have in index on StockItemName and StockLevel for both table?

Answer (score 0):

ok - I solved it - as there wasn't a unique ID on each table that could be matched, and rather than make one, I used 3 colums to create the unique ID and left joined on that.

SELECT sc.StockItem, sc.StockItemName, sc.Warehouse, sc.stocklevel
FROM stock s
LEFT JOIN stock_copy sc ON (sc.StockItem = s.StockItem AND sc.StockItemName = s.StockItemName AND sc.Warehouse = s.Warehouse AND sc.StockLevel <> s.StockLevel)
having sc.StockLevel is not Null;